# Is there a list of possible resources that a webbrowser will download when visiting a webpage?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I am building a spider some days now, and I am in a research on how to measure a webpage total weight in bytes. Through my research I came across this problem and the simplest answer was to get the content length of the page. But there is a small problem to that, content length in bytes is not telling us anything about the images that should be downloaded to the temp folder of the browser, nor the javascript or css links from the header of the page. So I actually backed up my conclusions on how to actually measure a page in terms of how much bytes are needed to be sent from the server to the client for all the resources needed to a weppage to work properly and not to measure only the bytes of the document only.
So I made a list of resources that a webbrowser should download when it visits a page:

```
all images <img src="someimages.jpg" alt=”somedecription” >
all js files <script type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js" ></script>
all css files <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somecss.css">
the ico file <link rel="shortcut icon" href="someico.ico">
```

Are there any other resources that a browser has to download when it visits the page? In other words, what is the list of all the possible resources that a browser does download when visiting a webpage?

Comment: what about videos? zip files? images with different extensions (.png, .jpeg, .tiff, .gif, etc)?

Comment: well yes zip file is a resource and i can find it if its accessible via <a href='file.zip'>download link</a>, also the images can be downloaded all from <img tag,

Comment: are you going to extract the `<video>` info, the `<object>` info, and `<audio>` info too.

Comment: well i think yes because those resources are downloaded from the server to the client in order to be playd.

Comment: The point I'm eluding to is the fact that there can be an endless number of media types that can come down the pipe. See my answer for further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an endless number of possibilities when it comes to media types that can be downloaded. In fact, you can "invent" your own as long as you tell your server about them.

[Here's a pretty good list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) to get you started. It's not a list of `tags` like `<video>`, `<object>`, `<img>`, `<audio>`, but rather a list of MIME Types.

All of these media types have a payload when downloaded and their size needs to be measured. Also, don't forget about [streaming media](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) and [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). Measuring those payloads can be a bit of a bear.

Comment: i accept your answer because this was the list i was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the three types you mentioned ( icon is a image file). one more file is downloaded when you load a page i.e HttpHandler files (.axd files).

any other files like pdf,zip, audio, video and other mime types, will be loaded if the page requests.

Comment: yep and as Case Florell mentiond, there are alot of internet media types that could be downloaded. He actualy posted the list from wiki.
Now I think I need to fix all those in a class of these and start thinking of how to measure those resources if they occure in a page.